# How to convert jquery code to angular 4?

Tags: jquery, angular

I have written some code using jQuery and HTML to remove a class after clicking on element. I am not able to convert it to Angular 4.

HTML code :

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   <li><a href="#myPage" onclick="hideNavBar();"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#login" onclick="hideNavBar();">Login</a></li>
   <li><a href="#signup" onclick="hideNavBar();">Signup</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function hideNavBar() {
  $("#myNavbar").removeClass('in');
}
```

Comment: Please understand that Stackoverflow is not a free code conversion service. It is really up to you to research how to perform different tasks first. Then when you have specific code related problems ask questions then showing what you attempted. This is all outlined in the [help]

Answer (score 1):

template:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" *ngIf="test === true">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a (click)="hideNavBar()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>Home</a></li>
    <li><a (click)="hideNavBar()">Login</a></li>
    <li><a (click)="hideNavBar()">Signup</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

.ts file:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  test = true;

  constructor() {}

  hideNavBar() {
    test = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> use [ngClass] directive to show and hide instead of ngIf.
>
> ngIf create DOM in runtime
> please refer this doc [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" [ngClass]="{'in': showClass}">
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li><a href="#myPage" (click)="hideNavBar();"><i class="glyphicon 
  glyphicon-home"></i>Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#login" (click)="hideNavBar();">Login</a></li>
 <li><a href="#signup" (click)="hideNavBar();">Signup</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

    @Component({
     selector: 'app-header',
     templateUrl: './app.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
   })

  export class AppComponent {

  showClass = true;

  constructor() {}

  public function hideNavBar() { // you can use in click function
     showClass = false;
   }
}
```